# ASP MVC4 Value was either too large or too small for an Int32 - but for a String?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

this is probably glaringly obvious to experienced MVC(4) folks, so apologies in advance.

I am getting the error "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."

The Class LEARNER has the Key LearnRefNumber which is defined as a String in the Class.
In my Model it is defined consistently as string (CSDL) and varchar2 (SSDL);XML Fragments for both of these are at the bottom of this text.

As I am passing a string and the property is defined as a string. I'm at a bit of a loss as to why I am getting this error. Is it the result of reflection by MVC? Can someone suggest a workaround?

The error appears to be occurring in the Find method of DbSet.

```
    // My Controller ActionResult Code

    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        LEARNER learner = db.LEARNERS.Find(id);
        // The above line generates an exception when I pass in the string 20044010
        // as id.

        if (learner == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(learner);
    }
```

XML fragments from CSDL and SSDL respectively follow:

```
    <EntityType Name="LEARNER">
      <Key>
        <!--<PropertyRef Name="UKPRN" />-->
        <PropertyRef Name="LearnRefNumber" />
      </Key>
      <Property Type="String" Name="LearnRefNumber" Nullable="false" Unicode="false" FixedLength="false" MaxLength="12" />
      <Property Type="Int32" Name="ULN" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="FamilyName" Nullable="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="GivenNames" Nullable="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="DateTime" Name="DateOfBirth" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>

    <EntityType Name="LEARNER">
      <Key>
        <!--<PropertyRef Name="UKPRN" />-->
        <PropertyRef Name="LearnRefNumber" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="LearnRefNumber" Nullable="false" Type="varchar2" MaxLength="12" />
      <Property Name="ULN" Type="number" Precision="10" />
      <Property Name="FamilyName" Type="varchar2" MaxLength="100" />
      <Property Name="GivenNames" Type="varchar2" MaxLength="100" />
      <Property Name="DateOfBirth" Type="date" />
     </EntityType>
```

LEARNER Class defintion

```
   public partial class LEARNER
   {
    public LEARNER()
    {
        this.LEARNERCONTACTPREFERENCES = new HashSet<LEARNERCONTACTPREFERENCES>();
        this.LEARNERCONTACTs = new HashSet<LEARNERCONTACT>();
        this.LEARNERFAMs = new HashSet<LEARNERFAM>();
        this.LLDDANDHEALTHPROBS = new HashSet<LLDDANDHEALTHPROBS>();
        this.LEARNERPROVIDERSPECMONs = new HashSet<LEARNERPROVIDERSPECMON>();
        this.LEARNEREMPLOYMENTSTATUS = new HashSet<LEARNEREMPLOYMENTSTATUS>();
        this.LEARNINGDELIVERies = new HashSet<LEARNINGDELIVERY>();
    }

    public String LearnRefNumber { get; set; }
    public int ULN { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string GivenNames { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public short Ethnicity { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public short LLDDHealthProb { get; set; }
    public string NINumber { get; set; }
    public short PriorAttain { get; set; }
    public short Accom { get; set; }
    public int ALSCost { get; set; }
    public short Dest { get; set; }
    public int UKPRN { get; set; }
    public int REC_ID { get; set; }
    public string PrevLearnRefNumber { get; set; }
    public int PrevUKPRN { get; set; }
    public short PlanLearnHours { get; set; }
    public short PlanEEPHours { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LEARNERCONTACTPREFERENCES> LEARNERCONTACTPREFERENCES { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LEARNERCONTACT> LEARNERCONTACTs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LEARNERFAM> LEARNERFAMs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LLDDANDHEALTHPROBS> LLDDANDHEALTHPROBS { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LEARNERPROVIDERSPECMON> LEARNERPROVIDERSPECMONs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LEARNEREMPLOYMENTSTATUS> LEARNEREMPLOYMENTSTATUS { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LEARNINGDELIVERY> LEARNINGDELIVERies { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the `ULN` causing the error. Maybe post stacktrace?

Comment: You say the error appears to occur there. Are you sure? Have you stepped through your code and verified, that the error occurs right there?

Comment: Hi Guys, I've made a correction resulting from James' suggestion and the error I am getting has now changed (but I can see what needs to be done). I have obviously been misinterpreting what I was seeing when I was stepping through with debugger. Thankyou both for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer turned out (in part) to be the datatype of the ULN property (amended from Int32 to Int64).

Corrected this as suggested and things are now working the way I had hoped. Lessons learned. Thanks again for your help.

Regards,

Lee.